# System-wide hooks with MHook

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, hook

I have this project where I hook some Windows functions `(GetOpenFileNameA, GetOpenFileNameW, GetSaveFileNameA, GetSaveFileNameW)` with MHook library. This is the code I use to install the hooks.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < FunctionsCount; ++i)
{
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleA(Function[i].ModuleName);

    //[1]
    if( !hModule )
        return FALSE;

    *Function[i].Original = GetProcAddress(hModule, Function[i].Name);

    if(*Function[i].Original == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    if(!Mhook_SetHook(Function[i].Original, Function[i].Hooked))
        return FALSE;
}
```

It is called from `DllMain` on `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` reason.

Now, when I inject my Dll using the `CreateRemoteThread` approach it works pretty well, but when I want to set up the system-wide hooks using `LoadAppInit_DLLs` mechanism my hooks doesn't works. After hours debugging I found that the reason is that my Dll is loaded BEFORE `comdlg32.dll` (which is the module where these functions are), and then the statement `[1]` returns false, then my Dll is not loaded.

The solution I've so far is to call `LoadLibrary` if `[1]` returns false.

```
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleA(Function[i].ModuleName);

//[2]
if( !hModule )
{
    LoadLibraryA(Function[i].ModuleName);
    hModule = GetModuleHandleA(Function[i].ModuleName);
}
```

I've found many site where is said this is evil and I agree (even when works fine). Also if a process doesn't use common dialogs at all I'm hooking functions that will never be called.

If anybody could help, maybe a workaround or an explanation of another way to set-up global hooks it will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to hook `LoadLibraryXXX` functions and after successful their execution check whether your module has been loaded (calling `GetModuleHandle`) and hook it if it is loaded.

Also it is a good idea to pin hooked dlls so they are not unloaded anymore.

Comment: Good answer, I will give a try soon. What do you mean with `it is a good idea to pin hooked dlls so they are not unloaded anymore`

Comment: Your hook algorithm may not expect that a dll is unloaded and loaded again. So it is much simpler to make a dll unloadable. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683200(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The thing is that I find the dll unloaded because of the order the operating system load the dlls of a process (dll in `LoadAppInit_DLLs` is not the last one), so in the process space `GetModuleHandle("comdlg32.dll")` returns `NULL`. Please correct me if I'm seen it from the wrong perspective.

Comment: You need to call `GetModuleHandle` after every `LoadLibraryXXX` call until you get your target dll.