# Windows: How to intercept Win32 disk I/O API

Tags: winapi, hook, createfile, intercept

On Windows, all disk I/O ultimately happens via Win32 API calls like `CreateFile`, `SetFilePointer`, etc.

Now, **is it possible to intercept** these **disk I/O Win32 calls** and hook in your own code, at run time, for all dynamically-linked Windows applications? That is, applications that get their `CreateFile` functionality via a Windows DLL instead of a static, C library.

Some **constraints** that I have are:

1. **No source code:** I won't have the source code for the processes I'd like to intercept.
2. **Thread safety:** My hook code may dynamically allocate its own memory. Further, because this memory is going to be shared with multiple intercepted processes (and their threads), I'd like to be able to serialize access to it.
3. **Conditional delegation and overriding :** In my hook code, I would like to be able to decide whether to delegate to the original Win32 API functionality, or to use my own functionality, or both. (Much like the optional invocation of the super class method in the overriding method of the subclass in C++ or Java.)
4. **Regular user-space code:** I want to be able to accomplish the above without having to write any device-driver, mainly due to the complexity involved in writing one.

If this is possible, I'd appreciate some pointers. Source code is not necessary, but is always welcome!

Comment: Did you look at Detours? http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/

Comment: It's commercial. I want a free one, and I'm willing to write one myself once I know what the main API and concept actors are.

Comment: You may want to look into mhook if Detours isn't what you want.

Comment: @easuter This looks very promising from the looks of it. It will take me a few days to evaluate it and get back, or mark your response as final. Thanks A LOT, meanwhile. +1  (You may want to repost your comment as a full-fledged answer below.)

Comment: @easuter I'll have to postpone my trial of mhook indefinitely but I'm convinced it will do the job. If you repost your comment as answer, I'll mark it as final.

Comment: @Harry, apologies for the delay in replying, just haven't been on SO much lately :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into [mhook](http://codefromthe70s.org/mhook.aspx) if Detours isn't what you want.

Here are a couple of problems you may run into while working with hooks:

- [ASLR can prevent injected code from intercepting the intended calls.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555644/hooking-createfile-in-notepad-exe-does-not-catch-api-calls)
- If your hooks are global (using AppInit_DLLs for example), only Kernel32.dll and User32.dll are available when your DLL is loaded. If you want to target functions outside of those modules, [you'll need to manually make sure they're available.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859133/system-wide-hooks-with-mhook#comment27831954_18859133)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with Microsoft Detours. It's free edition also exists and its rather powerful stable as well. For injections you will have to find which injection method will work for your applications in target. Not sure whether you need to code those on your own or not, but a simple tool like "Extreme Injector" would serve you well for testing your approaches. And you definitely do not need any kernel-land drivers to be developed for such a simple task, in my opinion at least. In order to get the full help of me and others, I'd like to see your approach first or list more constraints to the problem at hand or where have you started so far, but had problems. This narrows down a lot chit-chats and can save your time as well.

Now, if you are not familiar with Detours from Microsoft (MSFT) please go ahead and download it from the following link: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/ once you download it. You are required to compile it yourself. It's very straightforward and it comes with a compiled HTML help file and samples. So far your profiles falls under IAT (Import Address Table) and EAT (Export Address Table).

I hope this non-snippet answer helps you a little bit in your approach to the solution, and if you get stuck come back again and ask. Best of luck!